# Complex exponent $(z^{\alpha})^{\beta}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Complex exponent $(z^{\alpha})^{\beta}$ is not equal to $z^{\alpha\beta}$ as counterexample is $$i^{2i}\neq (i^{2})^{i}.$$ But my question is it true $(z^{\alpha})^{\beta}=z^{\alpha\beta}$  for principal values? Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For [principal arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value):

$$i^{2i}=(\cos\frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2})^{2i}=(e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}})^{2i}=\frac{1}{e^{\pi}}$$
And
$$(i^2)^i=(-1)^i=(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)^i=(e^{i\pi})^i=\frac{1}{e^{\pi}}$$

In [general](http://oz.nthu.edu.tw/~u9721201/penguin2/works/article/ComplexExponentiation.pdf) if we stick to the rule that
$$z^w=e^{w\cdot Log(z)}$$
where $Log(z)$ is the principal branch of $\log z$, then

$$z^{\alpha \beta}=e^{\alpha \beta Log(z)}=e^{\beta \alpha Log(z)}=e^{\beta Log(z^{\alpha})}=(z^{\alpha})^\beta$$

Comment: My question is about principal values. Is it true for principal values . For general values it is not true as mention in counterexample..

Comment: He countered your counterexample.

Comment: No its yours principal value not general value

Comment: $i^{2i}=e^{(2i)i(\pi/2+2n\pi})$

Comment: Plus $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\pi$ are within the range allowed for principal values https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value

Answer (score 1):

Write principal value as $\operatorname{Log}$.  That is: imaginary part in $(-\pi,\pi]$.

Now,
$$
z^{\alpha\beta} = \exp\big(\alpha\beta\operatorname{Log}(z)\big)
$$
but
$$
\big(z^\alpha\big)^\beta = \exp(\beta\operatorname{Log}(z^\alpha))
$$
and it is possible that
$$
\operatorname{Log}(z^\alpha) \ne \alpha\operatorname{Log}(z) .
$$
For example, $i^3 = -i$ and
$$
\operatorname{Log}(i^3) = \operatorname{Log}(-i) = \frac{-i\pi}{2}
\\
3\operatorname{Log}(i) = 3\;\frac{\pi i}{2} = \frac{3 \pi i}{2}
$$