# In general, $(z^a)^b \neq z^{ab}, a,b,z \in \mathbb{C}$ for $z\neq 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Why is it that, in general, $(z^a)^b \neq z^{ab}; a,b,z \in \mathbb{C}$ for $z\neq 0$?

I understand that if n is an integer,  $(z^a)^n = z^{an}$ for $z \neq 0$ because of Demoivre's Theorem. Does the complex power not work because of the principal branch or something like that?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: A similar question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1980763/complex-exponent-z-alpha-beta/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not quite the complex power, as non-integer powers give you examples already.

Take $z=1$, $a=2$, $b=\frac{1}{2}$. Then $z^{ab} = 1$, but $(z^a)^b = 1^\frac{1}{2}$ can be either $1$ or $-1$ (in the sense that $f(z) = z^\frac{1}{2}$ is a multivalued function).

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you. So the problem is that the solutions become multivalued?

Comment: Yes. Complex exponentiation is in general a multivalued operation.

Answer (score 1):

Stefano already answered for $z = 1$, $a = 2$ and $b=\frac{1}{2}$. More generally, we can take $ z =1$, $a=n$ and $b=\frac{1}{n}$. Then we have $ (z^n)^\frac{1}{n} = 1^\frac{1}{n}$.