# Let a be a complex number. Then does (aˢ)ʲ =(a)ˢʲ? Also does (a)ˢʲ=(a)ʲˢ

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

**Are the laws like the above one true?**
I used **euler's formula**.

**r(eⁱˣ)=r(cos x + isin x)**

and the equation says, this is true. Are there any **exception**?

Comment: In general, no.  See many posts here.  For example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1980763/442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $j$ and $s$ are integers, one indeed has ${(a^j)}^s={(a^s)}^j=a^{js}=a^{sj}$ for all $a\in\mathbb C$ (or $\mathbb C^*$ if you allow negative integer exponents, too).

If $j$ and $s$ are complex numbers though, things get trickier because the notation $a^j$ becomes ambiguous. When $a$ is a positive real number, the $j$-th power of $a$ is defined as $e^{j\ln(a)}$, however this is not possible in $\mathbb C$ because there does not exist a logarithm function that is continuous on $\mathbb C^*$.

Comment: Thanks. Does your argument also hold for rational numbers? Or just for the integers?

Comment: The same problem would arise for rationals. For instance, raising a number to the power $1/2$ would mean taking the square root, yet there also are not any continuous square root functions on $\mathbb C$ as a whole.

Comment: Ohh... Got it... Thanks for explaining me :-)